# MPMediaTypeMovie returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mpmediaitem, mpmediaquery

I am trying to play all videos, including the movies, which I bought in iTunes. But when I try to fetch the`MPMediaItems` then I get an `NSInvalidArgumentException` because the `MPMediaQuery` returns a nil object.

This is my function:

```
//get the iPod library
-(void) buildIPodLibrary{

    NSArray *items;
    // Grab videos from the iPod Library, of type == movie (MPMediaTypeMovie)
    //MPMediaPropertyPredicate *predicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:MPMediaTypeMovie] forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType];
    MPMediaPropertyPredicate *predicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:MPMediaTypeMovie] forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType];
    MPMediaQuery *query = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
    [query addFilterPredicate:predicate];
    items = [query items];
    itemList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"%i", items.count);

    [itemList addObjectsFromArray:(NSArray *)items];
    //[itemList addObjectsFromArray:(NSArray *)camerRollList];
}
```

I am running iOS 7.0.4 on an iPad 3.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try other flags instead of MPMediaTypeMovie? Maybe start with MPMediaTypeAnyVideo and then narrow it down to other types (MPMediaTypeTVShow, MPMediaTypeVideoPodcast, MPMediaTypeMusicVideo, MPMediaTypeVideoITunesU). 
Also, where are you testing this code? Hopefully, on your device.

Comment: Yes sure, I am testing on my device. I can successful access MPMediaTypeHomeVideo, so all videos, which I loaded from iTunes I can see. Also if I am using MPMediaTypeVideoITunesU it is working. BUT, for MPMediaTypeTVShow and MPMediaTypeMusicVideo the result is empty, what I don't understand, since I have such videos on my device, bought from iTunes. The issue with the nil object just occurs with MPMediaTypeMovie.

Comment: What are the videos that you have, if not a secret?

Comment: I bought a movie in iTunes, direct from the device. Nothing special, it's a comedy movie :) Any suggestions?

Comment: It can be that this movie is not marked properly. Anyway, just put a nil check before addObjectsFromArray and you're good:)

Comment: I guess my problem is related to antoher issue. I opened a [new question for that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122332/mpmediaitem-of-a-movie-returns-nil-for-mpmediaitempropertyasseturl)